# How to return the salary class for an employee given the employee’s EmployeeID value as an IN parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

Trying to classify each employee by class based on Salary. When calling the function I get no output.

Data: 
Class A: <= 10,000

Class B: > 10,000 and <= 20,000

Class C: > 20,000

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DisplaySalary2(p_EmployeeID
IN CHAR) IS
v_Salary NUMBER(10,2);

BEGIN
SELECT Salary INTO v_Salary FROM Employee
WHERE EmployeeID = '88777';
IF v_Salary <= 10000 THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Class A');
 ELSIF v_Salary > 10000 AND v_Salary <= 20000 THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Class B');
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Class C');
END IF;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Employee not found.'); 
END;
/


/*Calling DisplaySalary 2 */
DECLARE
v_SalaryOutput CHAR (10);
BEGIN
DisplaySalary2(v_SalaryOutput);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_SalaryOutput);
END;
```

/

Comment: Use `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;` before executing your PL/SQL block to call your procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written a plsql procedure and say that you are calling a function. If you display everything inside the procedure, then it would not be required to use it as a function by returning values.

Also note the comments to understand how to use the parameter `p_employeeId`.You seem to have hard-coded the values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DisplaySalary2(p_EmployeeID
IN CHAR) IS

v_Salary NUMBER(10,2);

BEGIN
SELECT Salary INTO v_Salary FROM Employees
WHERE EmployeeID = '88777'; -- You should use - WHERE EmployeeID = p_EmployeeID;
IF v_Salary <= 10000 THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Class A');
ELSIF v_Salary > 10000 AND v_Salary <= 20000 THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Class B');
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Class C');
END IF;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Employee not found.'); 
END;
/
```

And while calling the procedure, since you don't have any `OUT` parameters, simply call it like this.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
BEGIN
DisplaySalary2('88777');
END;

/
```

If you want to convert the block to a plsql function , you must use `create or replace function ..return returntype` syntax explained in this link.

[Create function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions.php)